# Javamail: Authenticate as admin user, authorize as other user

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-mail, imap

Imapsync has an admin auth option i.e. `--authuser1/--authuser2` that allows you to mimic a login to a user's imap account without knowing the user password.

This works specifically for Zimbra and helps to sync imap stores between backup locations.

However imapsync opens a new connection for each mailbox, and takes a lot of time to sync folders.

How do you achieve an imap login with javamail as an administrator user, and authorize as another user, and possibly reuse the connection for selecting multiple users?

Ultimately, I want to:

1. avoid initiating a network connection for each user
2. sync mailboxes without knowing user passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of this depends on the server...

If the server supports PLAIN authentication or some other SASL authentication mechanisms, you can set the mail.*protocol*.sasl.authorizationid property to the user you want to act as, and then connect with the admin's username and password.

Standard IMAP doesn't provide a way to "unauthenticate" and leave the connection open, so there's no way to switch to acting as a different user while reusing the connection.  Some servers support extensions that can be used to do this.

Comment: Great suggestion on the sasl authorizationid feature - thanks! Zimbra also supports this feature. However it's a bummer that you have tear down connections if you have to re-authenticate as another user. For migrating thousands of users via IMAP this is a major drawback.

Comment: Does Zimbra support any sort of unauthenticate extension?  I didn't see anything [here](https://github.com/Autobase/Zimbra/blob/master/ZimbraServer/docs/pop-imap.txt).  Otherwise, it's limited by the IMAP protocol spec.

Comment: Not that I know of. If it existed, it would be a fine facility for bulk sync'ing between imap stores.